# How to update a table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I built a database and I forgot to add Phone numbers, then I could not update it, is there a way I could? (the reason I am using 2014 is that I can't get the others to work on my laptop), How do you add more than 11 numbers in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014? I just get errors?

Answer (score 0):

What are the errors that you  get? Do you want to add a column to the table or do you have a column in your table that you want to update the rows with telephone numbers?

If the former, you can use `ALTER TABLE YourTableName ADD TelephoneNumber BIGINT`.
if the latter, there you might have an issue where you are trying to add int values to a varchar field or you update statement might be wrong.

Comment: My error is ' Saving changes is not permitted. The charges you have to require the following tables to be dropped and recreated. You have either made changes to that table that can't be recreated or enabled the option Prevent saving the changes that require the table to be recreated

Comment: Hi Cole can you send the statement that you are running or are you trying to alter the table through the design window? And is there a lot of data in  your table?

Comment: If you Google your error message, you should get the help you need.

Comment: sorry for the late reply I was every bus, yes I have about 41 people

Comment: Hi Cole no problem. You don't have much data in you table then if you say about 41 people. You should be able to alter the table easily by adding the extra column or if you do have the column already you can easily change it to the correct datatype. The statement for that would be `ALTER TABLE youtTable ALTER COLUMN PhoneNumber BIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your phone number field is an INT. In order to get the right number of digits you will need to ALTER it to be a BIGINT (or change to Varchar/NVarchar).